# Magento 2: Override Gallery.html

Tags: magento2, theme, overrides, html

I'm trying to override `gallery.html` in `<magento-root>/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html` by placing the file in my theme located in `<magento-root>/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html`.  Whatever edits I'm making to the file in my theme are not reflected on the frontend.  I've also tried deploying the static content with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed file right location you have to just run command,

First Remove `pub/static` files and folder.

Remove `var` from root.

```
Remove your browser cache and cookie.
```

In production or default mode:

run command: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Try reload page. your changes are available in browser.

Comment: That seemed to have worked, but it's definitely quite the task since you have to redeploy after every change.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes @Paul it is a long and annoying workflow. The alternative is full developer mode which is probably slower.

Comment: Be sure to have .htaccess in pub/static or configured nginx so all request go throught special php file

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done looks correct. Try the following to ensure that you didnt miss anything and there is no spelling mistake.

1. Copy the entire `gallery` folder from `lib/web/mage/` to your custom theme `web/mage/` instead of just the html file
2. Delete the entire var folder
3. Give full required permission
4. Run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Should work! Let me know if you are still facing the issue. Then we can see how to deal with the individual html file, though it should work the way you did.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working.  I'm basically just trying to alter some of the markup in the out of the box product image zoom on the product page.  I am overriding the correct file, right?

Comment: hi paul have you gotten solutions for this ...please paste your answer if you have